# Model summary in Pyomo

Tags: python-2.7, optimization, pyomo

Is there a way to get summary of a Pyomo model (number of variables, continuous and integer; number of linear and non-linear constraints; number of equality and inequality constraints etc) without solving the whole model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of of ways to gather information about a model.  Probably the easiest for what you are interested is the `build_model_size_report()` utility available through `pyomo.util.model_size`.  Note, that particular utility is not yet available in an official Pyomo release.  It will be part of the Pyomo 5.6 release.  Until then, you can get it on Pyomo master ([pyomo/pyomo/util/model_size.py](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/79296419f50a3789f5fddabfcd8e5d6a49f0c766/pyomo/util/model_size.py)).  The utility *should* work with most recent Pyomo releases (with little to no modification).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The utility you specified gives the number of variables, both active and overall along with the number of constraints and disjunctions.